# How to remove `.tex.bak` and `.bib.bak` files to the subfolder automatically?

Tags: auxiliary-files, winedt, jabref

The `.bak` files are same to be useless. However, it will generate `.tex.bak` and `.bib.bak` files every time when I edit my `.tex` files by WinEdt and `.bib` by JabRef.

So is there any way to remove `.tex.bak` and `.bib.bak` to the subfolder automatically? Or let WinEdt/JabRef not backup `.tex` or `.bib` files?

Comment: They shouldn't be useless. What's the problem exactly?

Comment: Like any insurance a backup is only useless until something goes wrong and you need it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can change them in winedt through `Options` → `Preferences` and then `backup` tab as in the following picture:

[image]

You can even create a sub folder by adding `%p\Bakfolder\%n%t.bak` so that all `.bak` files are created inside `Bakfolder`

---

Similarly in jabref, you can go to `Options` → `Preferences` and then in `File` as in the picture ↓

[image]